# Data Not Insert PHP Mysqli just Show A blank Page

Tags: php, mysqli

I have issue where inserting data with php mysqli, data not insert into database and just show blank page, no showing error, this is my code. note : $koneksi is the database connection, which has already been established.

**insert.php**

```
 <?php 
include '../config.php';

if (isset($_POST['posting'])) {

                        $id_member      = $_POST['idmember'];
                        $nabar          = $_POST['nabar'];
                        $kategori       = $_POST['kategori'];
                        $stock          = $_POST['stock'];
                        $foto           = $_POST['foto']['name'];
                        $foto_temp      = $_POST['foto']['temp_name'];
                        $harga_lelang   = $_POST['harga'];
                        $tanggal_exp    = strtotime($_POST['tanggal_exp']);
                        $tanggal_lelang = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");          
                        $rincian        = $_POST['rincian'];

                        move_uploaded_file($foto_temp,"katalog/photo/$foto");       
                        $run="INSERT INTO tbl_lelang_barang (id_lelang,id,nama_barang,kategori,harga_lelang,stock,tanggal_lelang,tanggal_expair,status,rincian,photo1,photo2,photo3)
                        VALUES ('','$id_member','$nabar','$kategori','$harga_lelang','$stock','$tanggal_lelang','$tanggal_exp','Proses','$rincian','$foto','','')";

                        $koneksi->query($run);

                        if (!$koneksi) {
                            echo "Error Input Data";
                        }
                        else {
                            header('location:nasabah/lelang');
                        }


}

 ?>
```

Comment: after include  please write this code to display the errors                                    error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: try var_dump($_POST);var_dump($run);

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 0):

after add echo $run; you can see your sql statement and then try to run that statement in your query browser.check what is wrong with it.
check your variables isset.

```
$id_member = isset($_POST['idmember']) ? $_POST['idmember'] : "";
```

do it for all variables.
thanx.

Comment: Thanks For giving response, the problem is , i forgot add form method in html code, ..thaks before